# how to start a sub activity in same view?

Tags: android, layout, android-activity

I want to start a new activity intent in my current view! How i can do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

after a great search i got it. I put my 1st layout in such a way!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/contentViewLayout" 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:background="@color/white" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="56dip"/>

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:scrollbarSize="2dip"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/background" android:layout_height="56dip">

    </HorizontalScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

When i have to start new activity in it i use follwing code...

```
public class MainActivityWithTabbar extends ActivityGroup implements OnClickListener{

    public LocalActivityManager activityManager;
    public LinearLayout contentViewLayout;
    public LinearLayout.LayoutParams contentViewLayoutParams;
    private Context context;
    public Intent nextActivit;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        context = this;
        activityManager = getLocalActivityManager();
        setContentView(R.layout.mainActivityLayout);
        contentViewLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.contentViewLayout);
        contentViewLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT); 

        nextActivit = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
        startGroupActivity("activity1", nextActivit);

    }

    public void startGroupActivity(String id, Intent intent)
    {
        contentViewLayout.removeAllViews();

        View view = activityManager.startActivity(id, intent).getDecorView();
        contentViewLayout.addView(view, contentViewLayoutParams);
    }
}
```

so in such a case it workssss....

Comment: I am aslo stuck with this problem. seeing your code i got What about getLocalActivityManager() How can i achieve this?

Comment: Just got the same problem here.. [This](http://codepad.org/u9DOM6po) is how I solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean an activity contained in a view? You can't do that. Views contain visible elements, activities are used for run program code.

If however you mean starting a new activity from interating with a view, as in the user clicks on a button, you need to implement an onClick() method, and start the activity from there.

```
layout.xml
...
android:onClick="onButton"

MyActivity.java
...
public void onButton(View v) {
  Intent i = new Intent(mCtx, OtherActivity.class);
  startActivityForResult(i, OPTION);
}
```

Comment: In want to display a new activity in my current layout. I don't want to use any other layout in for my new activity.? E.g if my 1st activity using a linear layout, then new activity should be display in that linear layout.

Comment: Ok, so you want to use the same layout for both activities? In that case you can can just specify the same resource in your call to  setContentView().

Comment: But in such case. Layout will be re-draw() and i have to associate handler fro tabs again!!!!

Comment: In that case you can inflate the layout yourself and store it in a variable accessible from both activities. In your call to setContentView() you then specify the inflated view instead of a resource id.

Comment: But i am not using completely that layout. I am using his tab-bar and my new activity has its own Layout, But that Layout should be display inside the old layout(that hold tab-bar).  any how i got it...

Comment: I read your own answer to your question. I'm sorry that I misunderstood your question, since it doesn't mention anything about tabs. Anyway, good that you solved it. Are you aware that starting new activities take a very long time? Usually you get much better performance if you keep the activity and change the layout based on selected tab.

Comment: You r right. But in such a case new activity just start 1st time. Switching to other tab PAUSE the current activity, and display when next time that tab click(instead of starting new activity.