# Start new Intent in old Layout

Tags: android, android-intent, layout

Is it possible to start and display a new intent in the old layout? I tried this solution [how to start a sub activity in same view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096633/how-to-start-a-sub-activity-in-same-view/4105053#4105053) but its deprecated now and didn't work for me...

Comment: Your question isn't clear and you are confusing several terms which have different meanings. Activity, Intent, Layout and Window are all completely different things in Android. If you edit your answer and add code showing what you're trying to do then somebody may be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

It will definitely solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

try it with `Services`. Services is run in background. So, You can to start new Intent from Services